# how to copy custom properties when making clone

Tags: c#, winforms, clone, datagridviewcolumn, customcolumn

i am working on a "DataGridView" in C# 3.5, in "winforms" application.

I have a custom column is "MaskTextColumn", i have some custom properties in it like : Mask,
"PromptChar" etc.

When i am making clone of "MaskTextColumn" my customer properties is not copied to new object, i want to make clone as it is with custom property value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the Clone method in your custom derived class.

Something like this:

```
public override object Clone() 
{
    var clonedColumn = base.Clone() as CustomColumn;
    clonedColumn.CustomProp = this.CustomProp;
    return clonedColumn;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. `base.Clone()`'s return value will be a MaskTextColumn so the `as CustomColumn` will make clonedColumn variable null and next line will throw NullReferenceException.

Comment: this method will apply as it is in CustomCell Class where base.Clone() as will return Class's object

Answer (score 2):

You should override the clone method to include your custom properties. As this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewband.clone.aspx) states,

> When overriding Clone ... be sure to also copy the values of any
>   properties that were added to the derived class.

The code goes like this:

```
public override Object Clone()
{
    object clonedObject = base.Clone();
    MaskTextColumn clonedColumn = clonedObject as MaskTextColumn;
    clonedColumn.PromptChar = this.PromptChar;
    // .. more property settings here
    return clonedColumn;
}
```